# Define rotations using vectors and scalars (only), without matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, definition, rotations

A *rotation* is usually defined as a matrix $M$ meeting certain constraints, such that rotating vector $v$ by $M$ equals $Mv$.

Rotations, however, can be defined:

1. The axis of rotation
2. The angular distance of rotation

Thus, rotations have a direction and magnitude, and should be representable as vectors.

Is there a way to define a rotation as a vector $r$, so that rotating arbitrary vector $v$ by $r$ is readily defined in terms of typical vector operations (such as dot product)?

If not, what is the closest we can come?

Comment: Rotations in more than three dimensions cannot be defined as you describe. Basic rotations don't have an axis of rotation, but rather a plane of rotation (e.g. the $zw$-plane in 4D), and you can do things like the rotation of "right angle in the $xy$-plane followed by a right angle in the $zw$-plane", which is already more complicated to describe. These sorts of things are discussed in Geometric Algebra/Clifford Algebras, but you need more than vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotated vector $\mathbf{v}'$ of $\mathbf{v}$ with angle $\theta$ about the direction $\mathbf{u}$ (unit vector) can be computed by
$$
\mathbf{v}'=\mathbf{v}\cos\theta + (\mathbf{u}\times \mathbf{v})\sin\theta+\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v})(1-\cos\theta)
$$
This is known as Rodrigues' formula.

Comment: This formula uses the cross product, and hence only works for 3 dimensions.  Is there something similar for n-dimensions?

Comment: Yes, there is, but be careful because in n-dimensions one can no longer describe a rotation as being about an axis. For example, in four dimensions there are two axes perpendicular to every plane and this would generate an ambiguity. You can find detailed discussions on it (for instance https://analyticphysics.com/Higher%20Dimensions/Rotations%20in%20Higher%20Dimensions.htm , I think you are looking of a formula like (15)).